# Is there any way to get Bing maps and Google maps to agree?

Tags: api, google-maps, bing-maps, map-projections

I was working on a mapping solution for WP7 and so wanted to use Bing maps as part of the solution.  I learnt that Bing maps doesn't quite get the locations "right", where Google maps seems more accurate. 
Are there some properties I can set on my calls to the API to change the results, or should I just switch?

Comment: It really depends on the geographic coverage in the region of your interest. We cannot easily answer to this question and it would create debate in here but not around technical question.
If you want to use Google Maps on Windows Phone, you have to make sure you have the appropriate license.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no you cant get them to match. Bing maps are modelled by NAVTECH, google maps by TomTom (Teleatlas). Complex road crossings can be modelled in various ways.